# How does git know only choose the tip of a branch when rebasing in this scenario?

Tags: git, rebase

I started with a history that looks like this:

```
O--O(A)
 \
  \--O(B)--O(C)
```

First, I rebased branch `B` onto `A`:

```
O--O(A)--O(B)
 \
  \--O--O(C)
```

Then i rebased `C` onto `B`, and this is what the history looked like:

```
O--O(A)--O(B)--O(C)
```

I was expecting `C` and `C~1` to be rebased onto `B` with rebase telling me there is a conflict.  However, only the tip of `C` was rebased onto `B`.

How did Git know only to rebase the tip of `C`?  Does Git somehow know that the rebased `B` was `C`'s parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the answer to your final question is yes. Git keeps track of changes. If it finds identical changes in a merge or rebase, it doesn't git in the way.

Comment: It doesn't git in the way :)  I just tried merging `B` into `C` and vice versa, and still no conflicts.  I'm really impressed with how well Git handles this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Git rebase just takes the commits you want to rebase (in your case `C` and `C~`) and tries to apply them onto the new base (in your case `B`). After applying `C~` Git sees that no change was done as the commit is already there as the new `B` and thus discards this commit as it is already present. The same would be true if you cherry-picked some intermediary commit earlier and then rebase the branch where you cherry-picked from to the branch were you cherry-picked into.